# Rock Paper Scissors does an extra loop before return, not sure how to fix this

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop

If you scroll down to my Game loop comment, I have my function game().
I want my game to stop looping when either the playerPoints or computerPoints reaches 5. Both of them have a separate return in the if else statements.
The problem for me is that instead of adding the final point and then returning the "you win" or "you lose" statements, it prompts the user one more time, and **then** returns the "You win" or "you lose". It doesn't interfere with the points, however it's a small bug I still want to fix.

When I review my code, I know my alert(playRound) is after my gameContinue declaration and I wonder if it's placement is the reason it is happening again and then returning my result. If that is the problem, how can I continue my game loop until someone reaches five points?
If that isn't the problem, then could I just get a tip on what method I should try instead? Thank you.

```
let playerPoints = 0;
let computerPoints = 0;


// Computer Selection
function computerPlay() {

    const compAnswer = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
    return compAnswer;
}
// One round of the game results

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {

    let rock = options[0];
    let paper = options[1];
    let scissors = options[2];
    let youWin = "You Win! ";
    let youLose = "You Lose! ";
    let rockWin = "Rock beats scissors.";
    let scissorWin = "Scissors beats paper.";
    let paperWin = "Paper beats rock.";
    let tie = "It's a tie, no points added."
    if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
        console.log(playerPoints, computerPoints);
        return tie;
    } else if (playerSelection === rock && computerSelection === scissors) {
        playerPoints = playerPoints + 1;
        console.log(playerPoints, computerPoints);
        return youWin + rockWin;

    } else if (playerSelection === rock && computerSelection == paper) {
        computerPoints = computerPoints + 1;
        console.log(playerPoints, computerPoints);
        return youLose + paperWin;

    } else if (playerSelection === scissors && computerSelection === rock) {
        computerPoints = computerPoints + 1;
        console.log(playerPoints, computerPoints)
        return youLose + rockWin;
    } else if (playerSelection === scissors && computerSelection === paper) {
        playerPoints = playerPoints + 1;
        console.log(playerPoints, computerPoints)
        return youWin + scissorWin;
    } else if (playerSelection === paper && computerSelection === rock) {
        playerPoints = playerPoints + 1;
        console.log(playerPoints, computerPoints);
        return youWin + paperWin;
    } else if (playerSelection === paper && computerSelection === scissors) {
        computerPoints = computerPoints + 1;
        console.log(playerPoints, computerPoints);
        return youLose + scissorWin;
    } else {
        console.log(playerPoints, computerPoints);
        return "I'm sorry please try another answer"
    }


};
//Game loop
function game() {

    let gameContinue = true;
    while (gameContinue) {
        const computerSelection = computerPlay();
        const playerSelection = prompt("Choose your weapon");

        if (playerPoints < 5 && computerPoints < 5) {
            gameContinue = true;
            alert(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
        } else if (playerPoints === 5) {
            gameContinue = false;
            console.log("You win");
        } else if (computerPoints === 5) {
            gameContinue = false;
            console.log("You Lose")
        }
    }

};

game();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a logic bug in your code.  I'm happy to ***tell*** you the answer, but maybe I can just give you a hint so you can learn from it.

Imagine the player just won his 5th game.

Put your finger on this line of code:

```
 alert(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
```

And at this point, we know that `playerPoints` is 5.

After the user dismisses the alert dialog, **what line of code runs next after the alert function returns?**

Here's another hint: `gameContinue` remains `true` after the alert statement returns.  What line of code were you expecting to run to set it to `false` ?

Comment: I thought that after computerPoints or playerPoints === 5 it would then have gameContinue = false and it would end. I appreciate you not giving me the straight answer. I'm still very new to JavaScript. I'm realizing while writing this, I for some reason thought that it would go to the else if statement after the if statement was completed, but instead it stops. Is that correct?

Comment: You realize that `else` clauses are not evaluated if the `if` clause evaluated to true right?  In an `if/else` statement, only one block of code is going to run, at most.  So if the `if` block ran, the `else` isn't going to run at all.

Comment: Okay, that is what I thought was wrong. In that case I see it's going back to my while loop and to the prompt statement, but what can I do to stop the the function from prompting once again,and instead make it return a statement depending on who won. Would I be able to use another if statement after the if statement? Should I consider a different loop?

Comment: What would happened if you simply replaced the two instances of the `else` keyword in your `while (gameContinue)` loop with a line break?  Literally highlight the word `else` and press ENTER both times.